# URL not found on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, webserver

```
<?php
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
$db_user = "root";
$db_passwd = "111111";
$db_name = "proj_manager";

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_passwd, $db_name);

if($mysqli) {
    echo "connect <br/>";
} else {
    echo "not connect <br/>";
}

$query = "show databases;";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
if(!$result) {
    die('error:' . mysqli_error());
}

echo "database list : <br/>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0] . "<br/>";
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

I making WebSever by PHP, But I have some problem.
I must saved PHP files at htdocs folder, and my Apache port num is 8081.
(MySQL number is 3307)

So I connected at http://localhost:8081/connect.php

But show this error 404 Not found

> Not Found
>    The requested URL /connect.php was not found on this server.

(http://localhost:8081/phpmyadmin/index.php work perfectly)

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Then you're file is in the wrong directory. 404 means not found.

Comment: Are the files one next to the other in the same directory? Sure about typos?

Comment: Please move files correct directory. 404 mean file not found on the server. Please make sure file is in server folder